# C Functions not returning

Tags: c

I am writing a program for class that has to use functions and I am not getting any syntax errors and have tried multiple times to change things with no success.  The function is not saving into the .out file correctly.

Here is the code:

```
/* LAB13, functions                                       */
/* Given the number of sides of an n-side regular polygon */
/* and the radius of the circle, find the perimeter and   */
/* area of the polygon                                    */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define IN_FILE "lab13.dat"
#define OUT_FILE "lab13.out"

/* function prototypes */
double get_perimeter(double n, double radius);
double get_area(double n, double radius);

int main(void)
{
        double n;               /* number of sides          */
        double radius;          /* radius of the circle     */
        double area;            /* area of the polygon      */
        double perimeter;       /* perimeter of the polygon */

    FILE * data_in;     /* input file pointer  */
    FILE * data_out;    /* output file pointer */

    /* Open the two required files */
    data_in = fopen(IN_FILE, "r");
    if (data_in == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error on fopen file %s \n", IN_FILE);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    data_out = fopen(OUT_FILE, "w");
    if (data_out == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error on fopen file %s \n", OUT_FILE);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* Print headers */
    fprintf(data_out, "\nScott _________. Lab13. \n\n");
    fprintf(data_out, " Number Of Sides     Radius    Perimeter      Area    \n");
    fprintf(data_out, "   of Polygon      of Circle   of Polygon   of Circle \n");
    fprintf(data_out, "----------------   ---------   ----------   --------- \n");
    while ((fscanf(data_in, "%lf%lf", &n, &radius))== 2)
        {
           perimeter = get_perimeter(n, radius);
           area      = get_area(n, radius);
           fprintf(data_out,"%8i  %17.3f  %11.3f  %10.3f\n",
               n, radius, perimeter, area);
        }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(data_in);
    fclose(data_out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
double get_perimeter(double n, double radius)
{
  double perimeter;

  perimeter = 2 * n * radius * (sin(M_PI/n));
  return perimeter;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
double get_area(double n, double radius)
{
  double area;

  area = 0.5 * n * (radius*radius) * (sin(2*M_PI)/n);
  return area;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/
```

The lab13.dat file that it is grabbing from is:

3.0   16.5
5.0   9.1
7.0   11.5
[The output from running the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Bzl.jpg)

Comment: The `fprintf` format `%8i` is bad for `double n;`

Comment: You don't have a question about computing. You have a story about a difficulty you face. You need to learn [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I don't even understand the role of `n` - the perimeter and area functions only need one argument: the radius.

Comment: @WeatherVane it's about inscribed n-gons.

Comment: @hobbs then if `n` is the number of polygon sides, `n` should have been `int` in the first place.

Comment: verify that your input data is being picked up properly, perhap by doing a printf on n and radius with "%lf"

Comment: @sabbahillel what better than checking the result of `fscanf` as OP does? And `"%lf"` is correct for `double` with `fscanf`, but for `printf` only `"%f"` is required.

Comment: @WeatherVane you would think, yes. But it's possible to make it work as a double, so I won't call it out as an error :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would appear that you need to learn how to use a debugger to step line-by-line through your code, which will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. Using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: If you had followed the discipline to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), you might have produced `int main(void) { double n = 2.82; printf("%8i\n", n); return 0; }` as the MCVE — and maybe you would have been able to find the problem for yourself like that.  Please do read about how to create an MCVE; it will help you ask better questions (or, at least, better received questions) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `n`, which is a `double`, using the format `%8i`, which expects an `int`. If you want to print a `double` but suppress any possible non-integer part, use a precision of 0, as in `%8.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is in the fprintf.

```
fprintf(data_out,"%8i  %17.3f  %11.3f  %10.3f\n", n, radius, perimeter, area);
```

i is not the format specifier you want, use f. Probably a typo